# PHP Include function not working

Tags: php, function, include

I'm trying to develop a website. I want that different sections of site that will be written in PHP will be in different file. Such as "posts.php", "recents.php" etc. I'm trying to use the function "include" to include the files from the directory "/codes/". But it is not working.

The thing happen is, if I put `<?php include '/codes/posts.php' ?>` in the middle of the original HTML page (the page is saved in PHP format). The code portion before the line added is working, but the portion after the line added is vanished. Don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You missing quote. `include '/codes/posts.php';`

Comment: check if exit/die is called in that script

Comment: You might also want to enable your error reporting so you can more easily see what's going wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I'm assuming @Bora meant a "colon" (`;`) and not a quote?

Comment: On a linux machine, won't that try to start the path from root?

Comment: Try to remove the first slash, eg `include 'codes/posts.php';`

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the semi-colon issue, also consider that:

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

[form the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/include)

so either `include './codes/posts.php';` or `include 'codes/posts.php'`, the first version looks for the file, relative to the current working directory, the second uses the include path.

PS: best use `require_once` or `include_once`, to avoid including the same function/class definitions multiple times, which will casuse issues (redeclaring functions)

Comment: @EsperoShoumma: No problem. glad I could help. If you don't mind my saying, though, the SO way of saying thanks is to upvote/accept an answer, by clicking the hollow V sign next to the answer (the one that turns green on mouse over)

Comment: @EsperoShoumma: After looking at your profile, I noticed you haven't accepted a single answer, please [read this to find out how to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). As a bonus, accepting an answer gives you +2 reputation, too

Comment: What does the docs mean by "the include_path"?

Comment: @Gnuey: whenever the docs mention `include_path`, the text is clickable. But in short: PHP looks for an `include` file in number of places: The current directory, and some global paths, defined in the `include_path` (`get_include_path` and `set_include_path`  allow you to manage these) just write  script `var_dump(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()));` to see which directories will be used

Comment: Ahh, I see. Tyvm for the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, you forgot to add a single quote :

```
<?php
// Enable error logging: 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Add a single quote: 
include '/codes/posts.php';
?>
```

Comment: sorry, I add the codes in my main script, forgot to add them here. add them now.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: No error. Just the rest of the codes after the line added is vanished. NO error reports.

Comment: Simply replace your defined keywords with -1 to see every error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have run into a pathing issue. `/code/posts.php` is an absolute path, so unless you have a folder called `code` in your base directory, it can't find the file.

You need to set up either a relative path by dropping the first `/` (`code/posts.php`) or you need to declare an absolute path to the home directory

```
define("BASEDIR", '/home/username/public_html/'); #typical path on a linux server using cpanel
include BASEDIR . 'code/posts.php';
```

Comment: `set_include_path('/var/www/includes/'. PATH_SEPARATOR. get_include_path());` is a better way, and doesn't require you to hard-code absolute paths time and time again

Comment: ooo, I haven't seen this before, I'll have to check it out.  It only affects the current working script?

Comment: the include path is used when the autoloader is invoked, or whenever an include/require statement can't be resolved as a relative path to the current script, just try `echo get_include_path();` to see what paths are used by PHP, usually it contains something like `/usr/shared/lib/php:/usr/lib/php` and some other paths... it's something like you'd have in a .bashrc file (`$ echo $PATH` on a bash shell shows something similar)